# MUI Toolpad : Error new query preview unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (openssl)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, openssl, toolpad

I created a new page then a new request

When I want to launch the preview I get this error

[error message personal api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6eEw.png)

I also have a similar problem with public APIs

[error message public api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owqy2.png)

The personal endpoint is accessible from other means of calling

To create this toolpad I used and followed create-toolpad-app (https://mui.com/toolpad/getting-started/first-app/)

I use node v20.4.0

Comment: try running `npm config set strict-ssl false` on your machine

Comment: This doesn't change how it works, but thanks anyway

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, it's a UI tool

Comment: Anyway it should be something wrong with your setup as I don't have such problem when requested `reqres`